# Correctly adding multiple expressions in ng-style

Tags: angularjs

I have a pill-box, whose background I would like to change as the user clicks. However, I want the bg-color to be `inherit` unless my `option.name == 'whatever`.  I don't quite know how to get everything to work together. Here is the statement

```
<div
    class="pill-input"
    ng-repeat="option in field.options"
    ng-style="{'width': 'calc(100% / '+ {{field.options.length}} +')'},{option.name =='Low'?'background-color','#b4ce98'},{option.name =='Medium'?'background-color','#fccf84'},{option.name =='High'?'background-color','#d95969'}">
```

Comment: `ng-style="getStyle(option)"`. And then you have all the power of TypeScript, in your controller, to generate the appropriate value. Such large, complex expressions shouldn't be in the view.

Answer (score 1):

- You don't have to (and you can't, it will result in an error) use moustache notation (`{{expression}}`) inside an `ng-*` attribute, as it already expects an expression (anything you place into an `ng-*` attribute will be evaluated against current scope, which inherits all parent scopes).
- `ng-style` can take multiple types of data and params, but I don't think passing multiple comma separated objects will automagically get merged into one (haven't tried it - but i wouldn't be so surprised if it worked).
  However, in practice, you don't need more than one object. Just specify each property and whatever you want to put in them, like in any other JavaScript object:

```html
<div ng-style="{
  prop1:expression1,
  prop2:expression2,
  // etc...
}">
```

So your tag could look like...

```
<div class="pill-input"
     ng-style="{
       width: 'calc(100% / '+ field.options.length + ')',
       backgroundColor: option.name === 'Low' ? '#b4ce98' :
                        option.name === 'Medium' ? '#fccf84' :
                        option.name === 'High' ? 'd95969':
                        'initial'
   }"
>Div content here...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the background color, you can chain it with the conditional operator and at last set the bgColor to initial if none of the option.name match *Low*, *Medium* or *High*

```
ng-style={'background-color' : (option.name =='Low') ? '#b4ce98' : ((option.name =='Medium') ? '#fccf84': ((option.name =='High') ? '#d95969': 'initial'))}
```